# What is the best way to mirror an ASPState database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

I'm not having issues with the actual mirroring part, but because of the use of temporary tables, IIS is throwing a bit of a wobbler if a failover occurs (I'm still testing a few things, so it's me causing the failover).

Is it possible (or even a good idea) to mirror `tempdb`? Or should I just accept that some people might get kicked out if the principal database is not accessible for any reason.

I'm using ASPState so that the two web servers (behind a load balancer that enables sticky sessions) can both get to the same session data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mirroring tempdb, that's a no. Have you checked [Step-by-step SQL Mirroring the ASPState database](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlmirroring.aspx)?

> If the -sstype:p parameter is not specified, then by default, the
>   ASP.NET sessions will be put into the TempDB database and not the
>   ASPState database. This confused me for a while. This is fine for a
>   normal non-mirrored environment because the ASP sessions will be
>   cleared if the server is restarted. But, this is not fine for the
>   mirrored environment, because we want to mirror the ASP session data
>   itself, not just the Stored Procedures! Also, mirroring is not
>   possible on the TempDB database. The -sstype:p parameter makes ASP.NET
>   install the session tables into the ASPState database, and they'll be
>   persisted if the server is restarted. This is exactly the behaviour we
>   want for a mirrored environment.

Comment: And this doc tells you all the possible options you can change using aspnet_regsql.exe (including changing the sstype). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx Just wanted to note that you should be able to set this option after install, not just as a part of install as might be inferred from the CodeProject article.

Comment: Mark, I really need to buy you a drink. Thank you. I was actually following those instructions to start with the other day, but somehow managed to miss that bit. I was using the InstallSqlState.sql script to install the ASPState db

Comment: Pleasure, honestly. I did a fair bit of head scratching the first time I tackled mirroring.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN - [Database Mirroring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx):
"You cannot mirror the master, msdb, tempdb, or model databases."